# Very long sql request nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, socket.io, request

I have a very big query from nodejs to postgresql that take around 2 minutes to load (the query also takes 2 minutes on pgAdmin).

This query takes 2 minutes because there is so many computation to do in a huge database so that's expected. I wanted to know if there is a way to shortcut this delay. I have thought about this idea:

- Use Socket.io and make a different query by using limit and offset parameter in SQL

What do you think about that? Are there other options?

Comment: Node will not be busy if this is postgres taking 2 minutes to form a result. As long as you use a normal database connector, your code should initiate the query, and then immediately move on to do other things, with the result coming in either via a callback or a promise resolution. So: can you show [mcve] code? Also, if you _know_ this is a super-long-running query, then have two API calls: one to initiate it, and one to ask "is it done yet? If so, what's the data?".

Comment: Can you share some more details?  Can you run the query with `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE) <query>` and share the output?